# python strftime("%-d") generate Invalid format string

Tags: python, strftime

I am trying to execute this code in VS code, w10 with python 3.8.

```
from datetime import date

date(2022,10,5).strftime("%-d")
```

and generate: **ValueError: Invalid format string**

The same code in Colab works perfectly, and the output is
5.
How do i solve this problem?

Comment: where in the doc have you read that this is a valid format string

Comment: you should report a bug at Colab, if it is a typo delete the question

Comment: I read this in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-strftime-function/ and works in colab

Comment: *”The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and platform variations are common.”*

Comment: GeeksForGeeks is *not* the Python documentation. That link is wrong. However, it's not technically a Colab bug either, since Python states the underlying `strftime()` C function may provide more functionality than that guaranteed by Python).

Answer (score 5):

The `-d` directive is not *guaranteed* to be valid in standard Python, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for details. Note specifically the bottom of that section (my emphasis):

> The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s `strftime()` function, and ***platform variations are common.*** To see the full set of format codes supported on your platform, consult the `strftime(3)` documentation. There are also differences between platforms in handling of unsupported format specifiers.

If the Python you have does *not* support that format, you can just use this, which will remove any leading zeros from something that *is* guaranteed to work:

```py
dt = datetime.date(2022, 10, 5)
print(dt.strftime("%d").lstrip("0"))
```

In fact, I would be doing that regardless of whether `%-d` worked or not, just so that my code is more portable.

Comment: But, why this works in colab?

Comment: @juliancaba: most likely because colab has a more expansive `strftime()` in the C runtime libraries its Python was built with.

Comment: Wouldn’t `dt.strftime('%d').lstrip('0')` be much simpler…?

Comment: @deceze: indeed, it would. Have replaced the regex with that much simpler one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

remove '-'. For example: "%d", and will get '05'.

Comment: I only need 5 and not 05